# Making one of a number of fieldsets display depending on a selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've made [a form to process user input using PHP](http://dendodge.me/?p=harvard), and the first question asks the user to select one of three radio buttons to fill in the "type" parameter - the available options are "book", "journal", and "website", and the code looks like this:

```
<strong>Type of work:</strong>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="book" value="book" checked="checked" /> <label for="book">Book</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="journal" value="journal" /> <label for="journal">Journal</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="website" value="website" /> <label for="website">Website</label>
```

Further down the page, I have three fieldsets (using `<fieldset>`), each corresponding to one of the types. I'd like to have only one of these display at a time, depending on which radio button is selected, to make the page look cleaner.

Unfortunately, I'm a total JavaScript noob, and my last attempt broke things really badly. The fieldsets already have IDs (`boxBook`, `boxJournal`, and `boxWebsite`), although they currently don't do anything special.

If it affects anything, I'd like the output to be valid HTML5, and to degrade gracefully, displaying all three fieldsets if the user has JS disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery I'd suggest:

```
// hides the elements using jQuery (so they're visible without JavaScript)
$('#boxBook, #boxJournal, #boxWebsite').hide();

// when the radio inputs whose name is equal to "type" is changed:
$('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function() {
    var id = this.id;

    // hides all the fieldset elements whose `id` starts with "box":
    $('fieldset[id^="box"]').hide();

    // looks for the element with the id equal to
    // `box` + upper-cased first-letter of this.id +
    // the substring from second-letter onwards of this.id
    $('#box' + id[0].toUpperCase() + id.substring(1)).show();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U2MKh/).

Incidentally, rather than performing string manipulation on the `id` of the `radio` input, it'd be easier to *either* use a `data-*` attribute to specify the precise `id` of the targeted element:

```
<input type="radio" id="book" name="type" data-targets="boxBook" />
```

And use:

```
$('#boxBook, #boxJournal, #boxWebsite').hide();

$('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-targets'); // or: $(this).data('targets');
    $('fieldset[id^="box"]').hide();
    $('#' + id).show();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U2MKh/1/).

---

**Edited** the latter code-block to meet the OP's requirements:

```
$('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:radio[name="type"]').each(function() {
        $('#' + $(this).data('targets')).hide();
    });
    $('#' + $(this).data('targets')).show();
}).filter(function() {
    return !this.checked;
}).each(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('targets')).hide();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U2MKh/6/).

Though, frankly, I think I've over-complicated it quite a bit. But it does work, and meets the needs specified in the comment:

> if one of the radio buttons is checked by default, the fieldset doesn't display. I'd like to have it default to book if possible

Comment: Better to change the values of the radio buttons to correspond to the IDs exactly. If nothing else, it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @Blazemonger: agreed; was editing that in as you commented, albeit I used a `data-*` attribute, since the `value` may be used for another purpose entirely =)

Comment: Yes, the `value` is used by the PHP that processes the input.Anyway, I've tried that code, and it hides the fieldsets, but it doesn't seem to display them again.

Comment: Edited the original code (and posted a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U2MKh/)) to show it working. I *did* edit the code, as I had a mistake in the string-manipulation part that caused an error. =/

Comment: Great, that works perfectly! Apart from one little thing - if one of the radio buttons is checked by default, the fieldset doesn't display. I'd like to have it default to book if possible, but it's not a particularly big deal. Thank you for your help! (I'd upvote you, but I can't yet)

Comment: That's absolutely possible! See the edit, and the [linked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U2MKh/6/)!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function in a script element in the head, roughly like the following

```
function chooseFieldset(id) {
  document.getElementById('boxBook'   ).style.display =
      (id == 'book')   ?'display':'none';
  document.getElementById('boxJournal').style.display =
      (id == 'journal')?'display':'none';
  document.getElementById('boxWebsite').style.display =
      (id == 'website')?'display':'none';
}
```

Then you can call id every time a radio button is clicked, using the attribute on every radio:

```
onClick="chooseFieldset(this.id);"
```

Comment: My answer is without external libraries, but I didn't notice the question was tagged jQuery. OP, what do you like better?

Comment: I don't mind. I tagged it that way because I have JQuery installed, so I'm able to use it if it's the best way to do it.